# Redirecting to different page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to redirect to a different page inside my application and cannot figure out what is wrong in my setup.

For redirecting I am using

```
  if($A->str_sifra!=$sifra)
      echo "Molimo pokušajte ponovo.";
  else
      return redirect('a_home');
```

In my web.php file there is a route defined

```
Route::get('PageController@a_home', function () {
   return view('a_home');
});
```

When I run the page it just reloads it with a shift to right in a view. What am I missing?

Comment: Shift to right?  Are you using JS?

Comment: No, just php, html and mysql.

Comment: What browser, then?  Pages don't 'shift right' without JS.  Unless of course by shift right, you mean something other than a visual shift.

Comment: I am trying it out in Chrome and Mozilla. No JS, and yes, I meant visually. It stopped shifting with last modification, though. I don't get what's the catch...

Comment: Without more code, all we can really do is guess, and all that will do is create pages of attempts.  That said, as said, pages do not shift visually without JS.  There is no windshield wipe animation when a page reloads or is redirected, so either you're using JS without knowing you are, like from a lib included in a page, or something else is going on with your browser, such as an extension that is interfering with the natural order of things.

Comment: OK, I figured shift / no shift difference. It stopped shifting after I removed return instruction.
Oh, and I am 100% sure there's no js, since I am writing everything from a scratch, without external libraries.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your routing is wrong, make your route using closures as

```
Route::get('a_home', function () {
   return view('a_home');
})->name('a_home');
```

And redirect with this `redirect()->route('a_home')`

Or if you want to use a controller method then:

```
 Route::get('a_home', 'PageController@home')->name('a_home');
```

And redirect with this `redirect()->route('a_home')`

The first argument is supposed to be the URL

Comment: Sorry, no changes again. Page just shifts to the right and that's it.

Comment: did you follow the routing in the answer?

Comment: shifting right? from what page are you trying to redirect to another?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your route has a defined name

```
Route::get('PageController@a_home', function () {
   return view('a_home');
})->name('a_home');
```

and try using this

```
redirect()->route('a_home')
```

Comment: Where are calling redirect?

Comment: I am calling it from welcome.blade.php, and it should open a_home.blade.php, both are located in view folder.

Comment: The issue is with the way the route is set and not with the redirect method

Answer (score 0):

you need to refere to the full URI

```
redirect('PageController/a_home');
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was quite simple. Instead of

```
if($A->str_sifra!=$sifra)
  echo "Molimo pokušajte ponovo.";
else
  return redirect('a_home');
```

I just needed

```
if($A->str_sifra!=$sifra)
  echo "Molimo pokušajte ponovo.";
else 
    exit(redirect('a_home'));
```

Thank you all for your help.